# strcmp function return value in another function

Tags: c, strcmp

I  know what strcmp returns but I don't know what it returns in this code.

firstly I have this function:

```
static int match_str(const void *str1, const void *str2)
{

  return !strcmp((const char *)str1, (const char *)str2); 
//if not equal return 1. 
}
```

and then I have this

```
if (match_str) return 1; // not equal so return 
else{  my code goes on} // equal so continue
```

What I don't understand is if str1 equals to str2, the match_str should returns 0. and then the code moves on.

but it adds a '!'　operater. it seems like if they are equal strcmp=0, it returns to "!0 " which means"!0=1 " . but if returns to 1. it seems like if they are equal, it will stop.

Actually, it continues if they are equal.

I really confused why " return !strcmp " works rather than "return strcmp", what is the purpose of using '!' here.

thanks

Comment: If you're using `1` as `true`, then `!strcmp()`, e.g. `!0` returns equality to `1` or `true`. Otherwise, if you write `strcmp()` you'll get a falsey `0` on equal strings and can't write `if (match_str(a, b))` to enter a truth block.

Comment: I would recommend to rename the function `match_str` to unambiguous name. I had found a open source code *(not C code)* where "compare" in function name was once used as "values equals ==> true", and in another function as "values differs ==> true". The name "match" is not as ambiguous as "compare" with boolean result. But even so in translation to my native language it is an ambiguous name. Therefore when you need primary/mainly compare the strings to equality, rename the function to `equals_str` *(current behaviour of function)*; or to `differes_str` *(remove negation from return)* otherwise

Answer (score 1):

From C Standard##6.5.3.3p5

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E).

*`>> What I don't understand is if str1 equals to str2, the match_str should returns 0. and then the code moves on.`*

Because of use of `!` operator with `strcmp` in return statement (`return !strcmp(.....)`), the `match_str()` will return `1` if string matches and `0` if they don't match.

*`>> I really confused why " return !strcmp " works rather than "return strcmp", what is the purpose of using '!' here.`*

The `strcmp()` returns `0` if string matches and non zero value if they do not match because it compares two null-terminated strings lexicographically.  The author of function `match_str()` actually wanted to return `1` if string matches and seems that, having this thought in mind, s/he has given name (`match_str`) to the function. The caller of `match_str()` function should be aware of this while using `match_str()` function.

```
if (match_str(str1, str2)) {
    //strings are equal
} else {
    //strings are not equal
}
```